# What does 00 mean on a sectional below the airport runway information?

Tags: aeronautical-charts

What does 00-50 mean on the sectional chart under PHNL (see picture)?

[image: PHNL Sectional]

Comment: It is the elevation (00' MSL) and length (5000') of the seaplane landing runways 04W-22W and 08W-26W. However, I am unable to find a source for that info.

Comment: The funny thing is that they obviously wrote it with italicized character O instead of zero. It should have been **00 - 50** but it is ***OO* - 50**.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

That is the elevation and length of the longest co-located water runway.  Elevation of 00, and runway length 5000 feet.

This information is found on page 16 in the current [Aeronautical Chart Users Guide](https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/flight_info/aeronav/digital_products/aero_guide/), which states:

> Runway length is shown to the nearest 100', using 70 as the rounding
>   point; a runway 8070' in length is charted as 81, while a runway 8069' in length is charted as
>   80. **If a seaplane base is collocated with an airport, there will be additional seaplane base
>   water information listed for the elevation, lighting and runway**

(emphasis mine)

In this particular chart of Honolulu Int'l, the first line of airport runway info indicates 13 L 123, which is a 13 foot elevation, lighting in operation from sunset to sunrise, and 12,300 foot longest available runway.

The next line down, which you are asking about, is the "additional seaplane base water information", described by the ACUG.