# Where are the seaport conventions for VFR charts explained?

Tags: usa, aeronautical-charts, seaplane

VRF charts contain information about seaports. For example, `00 - 50` in the formation block for `HNL` seems to be for a waterway:

[image]

Another example is `23W` for `1C9`:

[image]

Where are these conventions explained? I can't seem to find them in the Legend or User Guide.

Comment: [This question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/57275/62) is very similar, and [this answer](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/57277/62) answers your question.

Answer (score 2):

"00 - 50" means a landing surface at 00 feet MSL, unlighted, and 5000 feet (nominal, 4970-5069 actual) long.

At aerodromes with both land and water surfaces, it is customary to suffix the water ones with "W" (pronounced Water, not Whiskey) to avoid confusion.

Comment: Do you have a reference for the `W` suffix? I found a reference about `00 - 50` on page 16 of the Aeronautical Chart User's Guide.

Comment: @rvernica I've never looked for a reference, sorry.